# How to properly set-up Java SDK for android with IntelliJ

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, intellij-idea, libraries

I'm currently creating a simple Test activity that logs into facebook. I'm using the IntelliJ IDE. I've added the facebookSDK to my project and I've created a simple program. Problem is, I can't even compile the project. I get like 100 warnings and 3 errors:

[image: Problem]

I did some research and it probably has something to do with missing dependencies. The facebook SDK can't find some packages. What am I missing/doing wrong?

I'd really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the [Android v4 Support Library Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). You have to download it in the SDK Manager and add it to your project.

To add it, go to Project Structure > Libraries and add the Library from your SDK (should be under `%SDK_PATH%/extras/android/support/v4/`)

Comment: Great suggestion. It definitely helped to resolve some errors. Only problem now is that i'm receiving another error:

java: package R does not exist

IntelliJ can't find this import:

import com.facebook.android.R;

Any thoughts?

Comment: Usually there are 2 `R` in the project that you can refer to: The `android.R` which is used for system resources, and your projects own `R` which is usually imported via `your.package.name.R`

Comment: I've altered the import. Problem was that facebook revered to a different R file. Changing this import worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!